# How to loop a set of animations ie each row bouncing once in css animations?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm applying bounce effect on a set of divs, making each bounce one after the other using animation delay.I want to repeat the sequence immediately after the last row animation is completed, please help me on this issue. Find the code below. What I did was, calculated the total of animation delay and set it as animation duration, however the iteration seems to take place after quite a delay. How to ensure that the iteration repeats immediately after the last row animation is completed?

**//Style.css**

```
.detail-container .row {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 35s;
  animation-duration: 35s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 0.571%, 1.514%, 2.285%, 2.857% {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  } 
  1.142%, 1.228% {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  2% {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  2.571% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  }
  }

  @keyframes bounce {
   0%, 0.571%, 1.514%, 2.285%, 2.857% {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  } 
  1.142%, 1.228% {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  2% {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  2.571% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  }
  } 


.detail-container .row:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay:2s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay:3s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(4){
  animation-delay:4s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(5){
  animation-delay:5s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(6){
  animation-delay:6s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(7){
  animation-delay:7s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(8){
  animation-delay:8s;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code - you currently have infinte rather than infinite. As the css doesn't recognise infinte as a proper value, it is defaulting to 1.

Comment: I corrected it, however the code executes second iteration after quite some delay, how can I ensure that the second iteration happens immediately after the last row animation is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.detail-container .row {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  2.498%,
  6.623%,
  9.996%,
  12.499% {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  4.996%,
  5.372% {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  8.75% {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  11.248% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.detail-container .row:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}
```

```html
<div class="detail-container">
  <div class="row">1</div>
  <div class="row">2</div>
  <div class="row">3</div>
  <div class="row">4</div>
  <div class="row">5</div>
  <div class="row">6</div>
  <div class="row">7</div>
  <div class="row">8</div>
</div>
```

like Dkyleo said you have a typo in infinite

Comment: I corrected the typo, the iteration comes after so much delay, how can we make sure that it executes immediately after the last row animation is completed?

Comment: well you entered the animation-duration of 35 seconds and calculated at which percent which part of the keyframe animation should run. so you want to run the 1st bounce again if the 8th bounce is finished ?

Comment: Exactly, the 35 I calculated summing up the delays for respective rows

Comment: i want the first bounce to run again after the 8th one is finished

Comment: ah ok, thats not how delay works in css, animation delay is not related to any other object/element, i will edit my answer to continusly bounce

Comment: Sure thanks a lot, I took the reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231359/animating-elements-sequentially-in-pure-css3-on-loop/16290957#comment90660666_16290957

Comment: Please explain what you did as well, as it would be helpful

Comment: so i tried it, but its not 100% correct at the moment, your animation cycle is something like 9 seconds and not 35 seconds, and you would have have to recalculate your percentages to fit 100%

Comment: Why is it not 100% correct? and how do u calculate percentages?

Comment: i think now its better, the delay between 1 and 2 was 2 seconds and should be 1second and so on the nubmer had to be brough down

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, also please do tell how you calculated the precentages?

Comment: i also changed the animation time to 8 seconds now. i calculated the percentages base on your values ->  x * 35 / 8