# Add an transition-delay for each child element

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to fade in every 'a' element after the other has faded in. For example: 'Profile' will fade in, and then 1 second later 'Experiences' and so on. Does this require creating a list? So far I have gotten the elements to fade it all together. The code is below.

```css
    .menuitems{
        font-family: pal1;
        font-size: 1rem;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s 999999s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        position: absolute;
        right: 3%;
        top: 4.4%;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .menu_Title:hover + .menuitems{
        transition-delay: 0.1s;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <p class="menu_Title"> //menu </p>
    <div class = "menuitems">
        <a href="#">Profile</a><br>
        <a href="#">Experiences</a><br>
        <a href="#">Skills</a><br> 
        <a href="#">Contact</a><br>  
    </div>
```

Comment: `.menu_Title:hover + .menuitems > a{ /* css */ }`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294400/css-animations-with-delay-for-each-child-element or use JS

Comment: insert your code to js fiddle, so everyone can easily test what've you did.

Comment: Use `:nth-child()` to add custom delays

Comment: try this https://plnkr.co/edit/MhUpDSZiSiSaN3FeQg5c?p=preview