# Use nth-child as CSS variable

Tags: css, animation, css-selectors

Is there some way (without javascript) to make the nth-child affect the CSS?

For example when I have 10 images loaded, I would fade the opacity in, and give each image an animation delay of N seconds.

I can do this manually with nth-child(1){}, nth-child(2){} and so on, but that's obviously messy and has a finite amount of elements.

I have also tried loops and while that works out well for (10n+1), it breaks if i try to stray from the an+b formula (100n+10n). Also I doubt it would work to add 1 second for every n and 10 seconds for every 10n because one of those would overwrite the other.

*This question is similar to [this one from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294400/css-animations-with-delay-for-each-child-element) which is still open but a lot of time has passed and maybe there's a better answer these days.*

Comment: If the values cycle then you can hardcode one cycle (1n+0...10n+0 etc) in the CSS using nth child and then it will repeat. Not sure if that would satisfy your question so only posting as a comment. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: You want to add different delay for every child, yes?

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't a duplicate (time notwithstanding). Never mind, I answered.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Yes.

Comment: @PixelSnader BoltClock has already provided you answer (but I don't agree with CSS preprocessor part), you need JavaScript here.

Answer (score 23):

Please remember that you can assign variables in CSS too.

```
:nth-child(1) { --nth-child: 1 }
:nth-child(2) { --nth-child: 2 }
:nth-child(3) { --nth-child: 3 }
```

Then you can apply it like this:

```
animation: fade-in calc(var(--nth-child) * 1s) 1s forwards;
```

And here come some [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xgdnwre6/).

Comment: While this might be useful for people looking for similar/related css issues, this does not get at the core of my particular question. You'd still have to set the variable manually for each object. In fact if I were to use css variables, it'd probably be more efficient to generate them via php. (Both in terms of lines of code, DRY, computation time, data transfer and perhaps flexibility/robustness)

Comment: You can reuse those variable with different objects or components I believe and there is always more ways for a solution to be more efficient. However, what is the core of your particular question anyway? Do you want somekind of standard or built-in CSS feature to solve your problem?

Comment: The core of my question is "can I *calculate* this in CSS". Because then it'd be possible to efficiently work with variable grids, and you'd have support for infinite elements, rather than a fixed amount. 

It'd be nice if there were some sort of CSS standard for it, yes, given that there are already calculations possible. But I can understand if it falls outside of the scope. Pragmatically, many effects can be done with JS/preprocessing, but that feels like a lot of extra work and data saved.

Comment: Great solution Audi.

Answer (score 12):

CSS does not support using the current value of n, or the index of the child element currently being matched, from an `:nth-child()` expression as a variable, neither in `calc()` expressions nor `var()` expressions nor any other part of a property value.

The closest you can get is automating the manual process using a preprocessor that *does* support interpolating variables within selectors. This will work if you know the number of rules you need to build in advance, but only then.

Answer (score 3):

Set a an inline css variable on the element `style="--i: 0"`
Then add delay like `calc((var(--duration)) * var(--i))`

```css
.ball {
  height: 5vmin;
  width: 5vmin;
  left: 50vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  --duration: 1s;
  animation: move-right var(--duration) calc((var(--duration)) * var(--i)) forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes move-right {
  from {
    transform: none;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(20vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
          <div class="container">
        <div class="ball" style="--i: 0"></div>
        <div class="ball" style="--i: 1"></div>
        <div class="ball" style="--i: 2"></div>
        <div class="ball" style="--i: 3"></div>
        <div class="ball" style="--i: 4"></div>
        <div class="ball" style="--i: 5"></div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```