# Trying to use CSS variables or something like them in data atrribute or nth-child selector, or way to accomplish the same?

Tags: html, css

In this example, is there a way to make the `data-scp_parent` `data-scp` values css variables, such that the CSS that displays them as block could be one line and not have to know in advance how many child divisions are in the parent? For example, any row over 5 cannot be displayed.

The CSS variables using `var(--...)` don't appear to work for data attributes like `data-scp=var(--n)` or `nth-child(var(--n))` quoted or unquoted. Old [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508144/use-nth-child-as-css-variable) says could not do so for `nth-child` about six years ago.

Or is there any way to set this up to simply change the parent's CSS and display the desired child only, without knowing there are at least seven children in advance?

Thank you for considering my question.

```js
var scpParent = document.querySelector('div[data-scp_parent]');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('mousedown', handler, false);

function handler(evt) {
  let
     e = evt.target
     v = e.previousElementSibling.value
  ;
  scpParent.dataset.scp_parent = v;
}
```

```css
div[data-scp] {
  display: none;
}

div[data-scp_parent="1"] > div[data-scp="1"],
div[data-scp_parent="2"] > div[data-scp="2"],
div[data-scp_parent="3"] > div[data-scp="3"],
div[data-scp_parent="4"] > div[data-scp="4"],
div[data-scp_parent="5"] > div[data-scp="5"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Input an integer from 1 to 7 for data-scp.</p>
<div><input type="text"><button>Show</button></div>

<div data-scp_parent="">
  <div data-scp="1">SCP 1</div>
  <div data-scp="2">SCP 2</div>
  <div data-scp="3">SCP 3</div>
  <div data-scp="4">SCP 4</div>
  <div data-scp="5">SCP 5</div>
  <div data-scp="6">SCP 6</div>
  <div data-scp="7">SCP 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for something like _pattern-matching_ in CSS Selectors; for example, you'd like to be able to have just `div[data-scp] { display: none; } div[data-scp_parent="($1)"] > div[data-scp="($1)"] { display: block; }`. Unfortunately that isn't possible, but there might be some (script-free) alternatives if you change your approach.

Comment: This seems like an x-y problem. Please explain what you are trying to achieve instead of asking for making an assumed solution work.