# Add animation delay to li automatically

Tags: css, animation

I have a slideshow with CSS3 which have `animation-delay` in each child,
but this is not dynamic because for each tag I should add `nth-child` ,

Is there any way to add animation-delay automatically to li tags?

this is CSS code:

```
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
  -o-animation-delay: 30s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
```

I want to change this code to add 6s delay to each tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Animations with delay for each child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294400/css-animations-with-delay-for-each-child-element)

Comment: @IsmailFarooq Answers of that question can't solve my problem.

Comment: read the top voted answer this is not possible without js u can decrease amount of repetition with sass but u can't handle it dynamically

Comment: but only one way you can do this is inline style check my answer

Comment: @IsmailFarooq Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to handle it dynamically except adding inline style dynamically or with javascript

**for example**

```css
.cb-slideshow li {
  animation: FadeIn 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(.1);
  }
  85% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cb-slideshow">
  <li style="animation-delay: 1s;">test text</li>
  <li style="animation-delay: 2s;">test text</li>
  <li style="animation-delay: 3s;">test text</li>
  <li style="animation-delay: 4s;">test text</li>
  <li style="animation-delay: 5s;">test text</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to dynamically echo each part of the style, or intergrate it right into the css.
For example

```
.button:hover {
    border: 10px solid;
    transition: <?php echo $lot ?>;
}
```

Where $lot is the animation time.

I dont know how to get the nth-child(N) in php, but there is undoubtably a way. 
Sorry if this wasn't very useful, just wanted to say that php would be a good way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, but I should do it without server side programming.

Comment: why is that? if you just embed the stylesheet into the page it will only update once.

Comment: This requires an inline stylesheet to be updated everytime a new element gets inserted.