# Chain/sequence animation in CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

i want my buttons chronologically - the second button start animating after first button ends and so on ...
Could somebody help me achieve that effect ?

```css
a {
      padding: 6px;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 2px solid;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
    animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255,208,0, 0.2);
      box-shadow: 00 0 0 10px rgba(255,208,0, 0.2);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-100" href="#">100</a>
<a class="btn-500" href="#">500</a>
<a class="btn-1250" href="#">1250</a>
```

Comment: You could use the `animation-delay` property but to have it programmatically in sequence you should just use JavaScript.

Comment: but I want animations to be infinite - after the last element animation ends, the first starts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have suggested, use [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) to offset each element's animation.

In order to loop the entire group, multiply the animation duration by the number of elements and change your keyframes accordingly. Below, I've multiplied the animation duration by three and divided the keyframe percentages by three.

If you have a large number of elements or they are added dynamically, you may want to consider using JavaScript, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294400/css-animations-with-delay-for-each-child-element#answer-8294491).

```css
a {
  padding: 6px;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 6s infinite;
}

.btn-100 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.btn-500 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.btn-1250 {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  23.333% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 208, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 00 0 0 10px rgba(255, 208, 0, 0.2);
  }
  33.333% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-100" href="#">100</a>
<a class="btn-500" href="#">500</a>
<a class="btn-1250" href="#">1250</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add some [animation delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay):

```
.btn-500 {
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.btn-1250 {
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
```

Demonstration:

```css
a {
  padding: 6px;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

.btn-500 {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.btn-1250 {
  animation-delay: 1.3s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 208, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 00 0 0 10px rgba(255, 208, 0, 0.2);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-100" href="#">100</a>
<a class="btn-500" href="#">500</a>
<a class="btn-1250" href="#">1250</a>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbjuxt0n/)