# moving div from outside to inside the div and out again in pure css not using keyframe

Tags: css, css-transitions

```js
content1.className = 'start';
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('content1')).opacity;
content1.style.marginLeft = "0px";
content1.className = 'transition1';
```

```css
.main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: -300px;
}

.start {
  opacity: 0
}

.transition1 {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  /*margin-left: -300px !important;*/
  -webkit-transition: margin-left 1.5s ease 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s ease 1.5s, visibility 1.5s ease 1.5s
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="main">

  <div id="content1" class="content1 hidden">

  </div>
</div>
```

I want the red div to start from outside and go into the grey div slowly then after a few seconds it would go out slowly again. I tried using transition but it seems to now work.

My guess is timing is wrong?

UPDATE

I have the above now What I lack is the timing to show the red div then go out again to left. I have set a visibility but I think there is a way to just use margins?

Comment: You're not using pure CSS in your solution though. You're modifying the `classList` of the element. Is JS allowed?

Comment: im just adding class but i want the transition effect to happened in css.. but if it is not possible in js is ok

Comment: So adding class through JS is allowed?

Comment: yes if it is the only solution I cant seem to make it work to transition removing negative left margin then adding again even if i add !important

Comment: I think you're looking for keyframes, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119227/chain-sequence-animation-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to do this without keyframes, then I have two ideas.

First idea is to add the `transition` css property to the actual #content1 element. Because as you're removing the `.transition1` class, you're taking away the transition details.

If that doesn't work, then you might need to break this into 4 different "states".

That is:

1. **Start State:** Red div starts unseen
2. **Start-to-End Transition State:** `.transition1` class gets added
3. **End State:** A class is added to ensure that the red div has the same margin from the `.transition1` even after the `.transition1` class gets taken away.
4. **End-to-State Transition State:** Essentially do the opposite of what you did in the `.transition1` class.

EDIT:

Maybe ignore the "4 steps" because I likely was overthinking what you were asking.

I'm not 100% sure why you wouldn't want a keyframe, but I've added a few options you can reference depending on your overall use case. Each of these rely on some sort of trigger or event. In my case, a click. But this can be determined by any sort of event.

```js
var main2 = document.getElementById('main2');
var content2 = document.getElementById('content2');

main2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  content2.classList.toggle('active');
});


var main4 = document.getElementById('main4');
var content4 = document.getElementById('content4');

main4.addEventListener('click', function() {
  content4.classList.add('animate');
  setTimeout(function() {
    content4.classList.remove('animate');
  }, 1500)
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}

.main:hover #content1 {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}


/* Toggle Option */

#content2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}

#content2.active {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}


/* SetTimeout Option */

#content4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: transform 1.5s ease;
}

#content4.animate {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<h2>Hover Option</h2>
<p>Animation happens on hover and disappears after hover</p>
<div class="main">
  <div id="content1">
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Toggle Option</h2>
<p>Animation happens on click and disappears on second click</p>
<div id="main2" class="main">
  <div id="content2">
  </div>
</div>


<h2>SetTimeout Option</h2>
<p>Animation happens on click and disappears after 1 second</p>
<div id="main4" class="main">
  <div id="content4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: meaning i need to have a settimeout where i set the number of sec it will stay then add class which is opposite of trainsition1?

Comment: I've added three code examples to the post. Note that I'm utilizing the `transform()` property in css rather than margin-left. As that is going to give you a lot more flexibility for the size of the child element.