# How to start another transition only when one ends in CSS

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a navbar transition animation where I want a background color to appear on screen when someone clicks on the hamburger menu button of the navbar. The animation I want is that it first gains a vertical height of 100vh and then gains a width of 100% but when i tried, both animations are working together making it look like its growing out from the top left corner of the screen, I want the vertical height transition to occur first and then the  width transition. My code is below

The below code runs when I clicked the hidden checkbox just to trigger the transition effect

```
&__checkbox:checked ~ &__background--1 {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And the below code is what I am trying to do to make the transition happen

```
&--1 {
    background: red;
    width: 1rem;
    z-index: 15;
    bottom: 100%;
    transition: bottom .3s, width 1s;
    transition-delay: width 1s;
}
```

I am just trying but its just not working :(

Comment: `width 1s` is not a valid value for `transition-delay`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119227/chain-sequence-animation-in-css Try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe said earlier `width 1s` is not a valid input for `transition-delay`. So in order to make it work, **you should add your transition delay within your elements inline or separately** by a single value (`ms` or `s`), just like this:

Inline:

```css
&--1 {
    background: red;
    width: 1rem;
    z-index: 15;
    bottom: 100%;
    transition: bottom .3s 1s, width 1s 1s; /* name | duration | delay */
}
```

Separately:

```css
&--1 {
    background: red;
    width: 1rem;
    z-index: 15;
    bottom: 100%;
    transition: bottom .3s, width 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s, 1s; 
}
```

**NOTE:** For more information about it, you can read [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) or [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) itself.