# How to loop through array to show and hide text on ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qqrkia?file=style.css). It's a simple `React` app where I'm displaying an array of text. I'd like to loop through the array and hide and show the text. I thought I might be able to do this in `React` but I think now it might have to be with `CSS`. I can hide and show the first color but how can I loop through the colors so it would show *Red* then *Green* and etc.

```
*{
  font-family: Lato;
}

@keyframes fade-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


.titles{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.titles p{
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0; 
}

.titles p:nth-child(1) {
  animation: fade-animation 5s linear 0s infinite;
}
/* .titles p:nth-child(2) {
  animation: fade-animation 5s linear 15s infinite;
} */
```

Comment: You definitely can't do that in CSS alone.  You'd need some advanced logic in React/javascript.  Probably adding and removing classes with setInterval.  You could have a state variable as a counter to the position in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you have to keep the animation logic inside the CSS file, then you'll need the help of Sass/Scss for constructing a loop (see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294400/css-animations-with-delay-for-each-child-element/49102020#49102020)). Pure CSS will not be able to achieve this.

However, a hybrid of React/inline CSS could help. In your React component:

```
{colors.map((color, i) => (
      <p style={{animation: `fade-animation 30s linear ${i * 5}s infinite`}}>{color}</p>
))}
```

You might also need to update the animation as follows so that the show/hide happens sequentially. For the above 30s animation with 6 colors, the following animation settings will play correctly.

```
@keyframes fade-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16.6% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

To work out the animation math, just make sure the following 2 things:

For `n` items in the array you wish to loop through:

1. The percentage of time an item is visible on screen should be `100 / n` (in our example above, it is the frames in between 0% - 16.6% where opacity is not 0).
2. Each item is delayed by `m / n` where `m` is the length of the animation (again in our example above, the entire animation takes 30 seconds, so each item is delayed by an additional 5 seconds).

Comment: Claire LIn - your soultion works but it breaks on the last two colors and I can't work out why - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qqrkia?file=index.js

Comment: @lomine I've updated the code. Please try and let me know if it works. I've also added a bit more explanation on how to work out the animation math.