# css animations each child fades in one at a time, no javascript

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

My project requires the individual elements to load in one at a time with a slide and fade in effect. I have gotten the fade and slide in effects down but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make them appear one at a time.

I don't know if this will show up since I'm not the most familiar with google drive yet, however this is a preview of what I'm trying to accomplish.[example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/171SGRbVPKX-dtDiml8qXOGHzXRSq_jRN/view?usp=sharing)

I need this to work for 9 to 10 elements however, to simplify working this out I made a test code and have been working on it in codepen. I also took that over to jsfiddle since I noticed a lot of people use that instead. Here is the link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juliaann1990/z75prmay/)

test code:

```
<div class="block_group">
  <div class="blocks"></div>
  <div class="blocks"></div>
  <div class="blocks"></div>
</div>
```

```
.block_group {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 10px;
  animation: fade 3s linear;
  .blocks {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation: slide 3s ease 1000ms;
  }
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I tried making a tag for each element and then giving each one a delay, making the parent have the slide animation and the child elements have the fade animation with a delay for each, and giving each an second tag and then just adding a delay for each second tag.

We aren't using java for this project so I know there has to be a way to accomplish this without it I'm just struggling to figure it out.

Also I'd like to mention that I know my test code is going considerably slower than the example, I just want to get the animation right and then I can adjust the speed.

Comment: use animation delay for each child https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294400/css-animations-with-delay-for-each-child-element

Comment: I did try this but it was most likely user error so I will try again and respond again after

Comment: Okay so the nth-child unfortunately did not work out however a friend did help me figure out that I had made my own problem by over generalizing my class and id selectors making changing individual timing nearly impossible for what I was trying to do. Thank you for your responses!